# OAuth2 authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm really new on this site. The question is:
I need to write an oAuth2 authorization server which will work in such flow -

1) ABC.com has 500 users. A user tries to authenticate on ABC.com. ABC.com redirects the user to authorization server where he fills the login form. The user logs in and is redirected back to ABC.com.
2) ABC.com authenticated user tries to open DEF.com which on his side has an authentication form.
3) ABC.com sends an authorization token for this user received from "Authorization server" to DEF.com telling that verifies this user as ABC.com employee.
4) DEF.com accepts this token and sends it to "Authorization server" for recheck.
5) "Authorization server" sends a message/token back to DEF.com with Approved/Not Approved message
6) If the user is really authorized DEF.com redirects the user to index page.

Thanks in advance for your help.
If any code example is available, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, use **[OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/)**.

The authorization server or ABC.com should issue an **[ID Token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)** and send it to DEF.com. Then, DEF.com should verify the signature of the ID token. Consult an OpenID Connect expert around you for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing OAuth providers like WSO2 API Manager for this.